# How can a test called by Robot Framework return information to the console

Tags: python, frameworks, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a robot framework test suite that calls a python method.  I would like that python method to return a message to the console without failing the test. Specifically I am trying to time a process.

I can use "raise" to return a message to the console, but that simultaneously fails the test.

```
 def doSomething(self, testCFG={}):
    '''
    Do a process and time it. 
    '''
testCFG['operation'] = 'doSomething'
startTime = time.time()
response=self.Engine(testCFG)
endTime = time.time()
duration = int(round(endTime-startTime))
raise "doSomething took", duration//60 , "minutes and", duration%60, "seconds."
errmsg = 'doSomething failed'
if testCFG['code']: raise Exception(errmsg)
```

Or I can use "print" to return a message to the log file and report without failing the test, but that information is only available in the report, not the console.

```
 def doSomething(self, testCFG={}):
    '''
    Do a process and time it. 
    '''
testCFG['operation'] = 'doSomething'
startTime = time.time()
response=self.Engine(testCFG)
endTime = time.time()
duration = int(round(endTime-startTime))
print "doSomething took", duration//60 , "minutes and", duration%60, "seconds."
errmsg = 'doSomething failed'
if testCFG['code']: raise Exception(errmsg)
```

If I use the "print" option I get this:

```
==============================================================================
Do Something :: Do a process to a thing(Slow Process).                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
doSomething :: Overall Results                                        | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

What I want is this:

```
==============================================================================
Do Something :: Do a process to a thing(Slow Process).                | PASS |
doSomething took 3 minutes and 14 seconds.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
doSomething :: Overall Results                                        | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are using Python you have two simple possibilities:

1. Write your messages to the `stderr`. These messages are written both to Robot's log file and to the console. A limitation is that the messages end up to the console only after the keyword you are executing finishes. A bonus is that this approach works also with Java based libraries.
2. Write your messages to `sys.__stdout__` in Python. Robot only intercepts `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` and leaves `sys.__stdout__` (and `sys.__stderr__`) alone (as all well behaving Python programs should). These messages only end up to the console, but you can write them also to `sys.stdout` to get them also to the log file.

Comment: Thank you Pekka, had I known you were here as well I would not have asked the same question in two places.

Comment: Glad I could help. I noticed this question pretty much by accident and could easily paste the same answer I send to robotframework-users. I might start following SO a bit more closely in the future. Until we get separate robotframework tag (not sure what it takes to create one), you might want to use automated-tests tag with Robot related questions.

Comment: To create a tag you need a reputation of 1500.  Neither of us have that.

Comment: We could ask someone with enough reputation to create such a tag. Until there are more Robot related questions here that's probably not worth it, though.

Comment: Looks like someone created our robot framework tag.  Thanks, Bryan!

Comment: Is this very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120893/how-to-customize-robot-framework-test-reports/9087623#comment21059586_9087623 where one answer was to use Set Test Message for those kinds of things?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the robot.api library. This is the document for the library

https://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/robot/api/logger.html

Answer (score 0):

Have your lib return a string, then use `Set Test Message` to display it.

```
My Test Case  [Documentation]  display data returned from lib call
  ${r} =  mylib.libfunc  arg=param
  Set Test Message  libfunc returned ${r}
```

ref: http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Message

Updates:

1. new link: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Message
2. new `Log To Console` command outputs to console in real time (i.e. during test execution, as opposed to `Set Test Message` which outputs only at the end of the test case.)

Comment: New link: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Message