# how to customize robot framework test reports

Tags: python, testing, robotframework

I want to customize robot framework test report, in order to fit my need.
Where can I find the related python source that handle this feature?

Or I need to create a 3rd party library to handle this?

Comment: What kind of customization are you trying to do? We are currently rewriting the log/report generation almost from ground up. Current source is at http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/source/browse/#hg%2Fsrc%2Frobot%2Fserializing but the new version will be available within a month

Comment: Hi @janne I'd like to modify the layout of the HTML test report, add some visualize summary and so on.. Thank you very much for providing me the link. You can post it as an answer if you like, and then I will accept it.

Comment: @janne, another question. Are there any API for the test report output feature? I mean allow users create there own template.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to create your own report from scratch. The XML output is very easy to parse. You can turn off the generation of reports with command line options (eg: `--log NONE and --report NONE`). Then, create a script that generates any type of report that you want.

Answer (score 4):

One method, kind of lame but workable, is to use the keyword, 'Set Test Message'.  This lets you put text into the test message column of the report.  Whenever the test passes, you will see the message.  If it fails, you see the normal failure message.

It would be great to be able to dynamically insert a documentation line, though.  I'd love to be able to have the keyword, "Set Documentation Message" so that in the keyword logic I could set it, instead of copying a '[Documentation]   blah, blah, blah' onto every line that it applies to.

Comment: You got lucky. `Set Test Documentation` keyword was added in RF 2.7: http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/ReleaseNotes27

Comment: That's not lame, that's cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly modify the template located at

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robot/htmldata/rebot/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the robot framework using the steps mentioned in the following steps. [Robo Report](https://github.com/vvkalkundri/RoboReport)

You can get a html report that looks like [HTML Report](https://github.com/vvkalkundri/RoboReport/blob/master/graph.html)