# How do i need to scroll end of the listview using robot framework?

Tags: android, python, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I tried using following keyword to scroll down to the listview in android:

```
***Keyword*** T1
    : FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE   100
    \    ${val}  evaluate  0.1*${index}
    \    run keyword  Swipe   0.1     0.4     ${val}     ${val}
```

It is scrolling properly, but unable to move immediately to the end of the listview. Is there is any way to move down to the listview immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go at bottom (End) of your page you should use below piece.
if list is present in frame  than make sure  to select frame

```
Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
```

If you are try to scroll anything that is present on web page you should use this piece of code.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Suite TearDown  Close Browser

*** Variables ***
${SCROLL_HIEGHT}    0

*** Test Cases ***
Scroll Page
        Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540784/how-can-a-test-called-by-robot-framework-return-information-to-the-console?rq=1   firefox
        Maximize Browser Window
        Sleep    2s 
        :FOR  ${i}  IN RANGE    0   20
    \   ${SCROLL_HIEGHT}=   Evaluate    ${SCROLL_HIEGHT}+25
    \   Sleep    .4
        \   Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0, ${SCROLL_HIEGHT})
```

Use loop boundaries according to your page hieght and 
Scroll height according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi, I am trying for android mobile testing listview scrolling not for web page automation, Let me know if you found anything  related to android listview scrolling.

Comment: He ask about Android , you share the answer WebDriver